# What template is stackoverflow.com based off?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, web

I have seen the question answer template used on Stack Overflow several times on other sites– but I can't figure out what it's called.

How does one go about making a Q&A site like Stack Overflow for one's software.

Comment: Look in the upper-left corner of the page =) (Hint: StackExchange)

Comment: The other sites are part of stackexchange, the parent site to all of these Q&A sites. I don't think it's a public template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Comment: This seems like an okay question to me. It's a perfectly reasonable thing to ask if you don't know that SO is the original.

Comment: On second thought, I was probably focusing too much on the title.

Answer (score 4):

The Stack Overflow template is original to my knowledge and well thought out.

There are many clones and searching will reveal a whole list for you.

If you need something just for your own product etc, then you could easily use this Q&A system http://www.osqa.net/ which is used on quite a few other sites such as http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/

Comment: Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: